# Missing templates in VS2022 v17.8

Tags: visual-studio

I've got the problem with missing project templates after the latest update of Visual Studio 2022. Namely, there was a project template called "ASP.NET Core with React.js" but it just disappeared in new 17.8. version. Does anyone know is it possible to rollback to older versions such as 17.5. or 17.6.?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer for you. If it was helpful to you, you can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about React and ASP.NET Core? If you can't find it you can try using Visual Studio Installer to uninstall ASP.NET and web development first and then reinstall it.

[image]

Or you need to use Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio.

Update:

[image]

Repair:

[image]